# AND query not working as expected in nest C#

Tags: nest

Individual queries via nest retrieve what I am expecting but when I try and use both queries to create a logical AND query it seems to only return values for the MatchPhrase and it ignores the DateRange.

The individual queries are..

```
resultsList = Client.SearchAsync<AuditLog>(s => s
   .From(0)
   .Take(10)
   .Query(q => q
      .MatchPhrase(mp => mp
         .Field("audit_Action")
         .Query("Successful logout")
      )
   )
).Result.Documents.ToList();
```

And...

```
resultsList = Client.SearchAsync<AuditLog>(s => s
   .From(0)
   .Take(10)
   .Query(q => q
      .DateRange(r => r
         .Field("audit_TimeStamp")
         .GreaterThanOrEquals("2017-03-07T13:00:00")
         .LessThanOrEquals("2017-03-07T14:00:00")
      )
   )
).Result.Documents.ToList();
```

These two queries return the correct amount of rows, 10 and 5 respectively but when I combine the two queries it still returns 10 rows, not 1 as expected. My revised query is...

```
resultsList = Client.SearchAsync<AuditLog>(s => s
   .From(0)
   .Take(10)
   .Query(q => q
      .Bool(b => b
         .Must(m1 => m1
            .DateRange(r => r
               .Field("audit_TimeStamp")
               .GreaterThanOrEquals("2017-03-07T13:00:00")
               .LessThanOrEquals("2017-03-07T14:00:00")
            )
         )
         .Must(m1 => m1
            .MatchPhrase(m => m
               .Field("audit_Action")
               .Query("Successful logout")
            )
         )
      )
   )
).Result.Documents.ToList();
```

Not sure what is wrong but think it is probably because I'm using to MUSTs and they are being OR'd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second must is overwriting first must clause. You need to pass all queries to the same must

You need to define query like below.

```
Client.Search<AuditLog>(s => s
                                    .From(0)
                                    .Take(10)
                                    .Query(q => q
                                       .Bool(b => b
                                          .Must(m1 => m1
                                             .DateRange(r => r
                                                .Field("audit_TimeStamp")
                                                .GreaterThanOrEquals("2017-03-07T13:00:00")
                                                .LessThanOrEquals("2017-03-07T14:00:00")
                                             ),
                                             m1=>m1.MatchPhrase(m => m
                                                .Field("audit_Action")
                                                .Query("Successful logout")
                                             )
                                          )

                                       )
                                    )
                                );
```